# Making Grails Spring Security To Authenticate Users With Email

Tags: grails, spring-security, grails-plugin

We have a grails app which is working fine with the spring security plugin. As per our requirements, we see that there is no need for `username` field.

Without `username` field in the DB we wish to authenticate the users with `email` and their password. Is that possible to do so?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply put in config.groovy

```
grails{
    plugins{
             springsecurity{
                    userLookup.usernamePropertyName = 'myemailfield'
                 }
        }
}
```

where myemailfield is the name of your email field in user domain

or we can do also:

```
grails.plugins.springsecurity.userLookup.usernamePropertyName = 'email'
```

Comment: Thanks. I have edited your answer by adding other options available and also correcting the spelling mistake ;)